# How can I access the ng-model of an element when scraping data off a site that uses angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-scraping

We have a wholesale vendor that we buy a lot of products from, which we customize and resell for our customers. Some of their products we stock, others we order when a customer orders them. We advertise these products on our web site, and make them available to be purchased (with customization, etc.) via our site, but the vendor often has a limited supply (especially of these "special ordered" products that aren't as frequently sold), so we don't advertise products or make them available for purchase if the vendor's supply is too low.

Now, there are a lot of these products, and each day we need to know what the vendor's available quantity is for each of them so we don't end up selling something we can't get. For years we've begged the vendor to provide us with a web service or an ftp site with a daily dump or any way at all to get this available inventory data other than by scraping their web site, believe me we've begged them quite a lot, and they just won't do it. (They'll say we're too busy, maybe by next year we'll have something, but 10 years later they still don't have anything.) So we have to scrape their site. And they know we're doing it, and it's not something either of us are super happy about, but it has to be done if we're going to sell these products.

Well, their site now uses Angular, and is a real pain in the butt to try to scrape. For over a year we had a Selenium based scraper working just fine, but after some changes they made a few months back, it just falls over trying to run the JavaScript on their site. (I get various obscure errors and exceptions, and things that would normally work just fine just don't because there seems to be javascript triggered on events related to whatever html element I'm trying to interact with, and it seems like Selenium has trouble processing that JavaScript.) I've tried many flavors of selenium, all the available web drivers, many different configuration attempts, all kinds of different option settings and such, I just can't get the thing to successfully scrape that site anymore, so I've resorted to using a browser with web-security disabled, and running a JavaScript program that opens their site in a separate window. (I can't just open it in a frame, because they use window.top a lot. Because they use frames themselves. Fun fun.)

So after my scraper logs in and does a bit of navigation, which it has no trouble doing, it has to put a search value into a search box and click the search button. Well, the value shows up in the search box just fine, but when my program clicks their search button, their JavaScript visibly clears the search field, and ends up producing an error message about more than 2000 products being returned by my search, as though I'd entered a blank value.

In examining their page, I see this:

```
<textarea id="searchBox" ng-model="searchParams.searchString" rows="3"
          ng-blur="formatSearch()" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched"
          style="">
</textarea>
```

So it seems that even though I'm putting the search value into the textarea by sending keypress events to the input (and I've also tried just setting the input's value as well), still, that searchParams.searchString ng-model isn't getting updated, so when formatSearch() runs, it takes what's in that model (an emtpy string), formats it, and puts that into the field. Or at least that's what it looks like is happening.

How can I set that searchParams.searchString to the search value I'm trying to put into the search box? I can get the angular scope of the element, but it seems I need the controller scope or something. I don't see any element that specifies an ng-controller.. oh wait, here is a containing div in the search box's somewhat distant ancestry:

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-class="routeClassName"
     class="fluid-container ng-scope ViewProducts" style="">
```

.. maybe I'll end up answering my own question.

(I wish I could post a link to the vendor's site and our login info so you guys could try out ideas and such, but obviously I can't do that.)

Comment: Sending keypress events seems like the right approach. Are you sure the site doesn't just have a bug? Try typing in the same thing your scraper is typing and see what happens.

Comment: Their site does work when I type the product number into the search box and click the search button manually as a user, but something odd is going on, because the keypress events I'm sending are resulting in the value visibly showing up. But when the blur event fires, my value disappears. Or it seems that way.

Comment: My guess is that this doesn't have anything to do with Angular. If you're interacting with the page at the level of events, you shouldn't have to worry about that stuff. I would start by making absolutely sure the events you're generating as a human (that work) are exactly the same as the events you're sending with your scraper. Then look for differences in the client; how is the scaper loading the page and running the js? Maybe it's using a weird version of Chromium or something else unusual.

Comment: I don't know what else to do to make sure the events I'm generating as a human are the same as the events I'm sending with my scraper beyond what I've already done.  And I'm interacting as a human with the browser window that my scraper opened, so, there's no difference in the client. The version of Chromium is whatever the latest version of Opera is using.  I did manage to figure out how to set that value with the angular that's running on that page. I'll submit an answer to the question.

Comment: I mean there must be some difference between the events I'm sending with my program and events generated when I enter the search value with the keyboard. I'd need to focus the element, send a keydown and then a keypress and then a keyup to the content frame's window (because events drill down and then bubble back up, and who knows where the key handler is); but events have quite a few parameters and potential permutations of them, so, directly updating that model just seemed like a much shorter path to victory, at least for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding angular to the page that I'm opening that loads my scraper which then loads the vendor's site and then using that to try to get access to the angular scope needed, but that didn't work. I tried to access angular running on their page via their window object, but it wasn't there.

Here's what I had to do:

```
    var f = self.sitewin.top.document.querySelector('#contentFrame');
    f.contentWindow.angular.element(tag).scope().searchParams.searchString = self.puid;
```

That worked.

'self' is my scraper object. 'sitewin' is the site's window. 'tag' is the element which I found like this:

```
find: function (selector) {
    var self = GTPScraper;
    var tag = self.sitewin.document.querySelector(selector);
    if (tag) return tag;
    try {
        tag = self.sitewin.top.document.querySelector('#contentFrame').contentDocument.querySelector(selector);
    }
    catch (e) {
        // swallow errors about things that are null because something hasn't loaded yet - this function gets retried for up to a timeout length
    }
    return tag;
},
```

'self.puid' is the "product unit id" I'm entering into the search box.

I guess the take-away here is that angular can end up being loaded into a frame of the scraped site's window, and if that happens, you can access it via that frame's contentWindow, and then you can access element scopes from there, and access their models from there.

This is working - After setting searchParams.searchString = self.puid, it clicks the search button, and now the product page shows up. Halellujah.